# How to use horizontal lock on my mouse with AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking to press "`Alt + MiddleMouse + Drag L/R`" which allows me to scroll horizontally `(L/R)` in a software I use, but the problem is it also allows you to scroll vertically. If you ever so slightly move your mouse up or down, it will also pan the view up/down (So it isn't `"TRUE"` horizontal scrolling like in most programs)

I'm curious when pressing this hotkey as normal, it will disable vertical mouse movement ONLY allowing for `L/R` movement.

AHK `v1.1` preferably!

I'm not sure what to do but I do suspect this could be done.